# Python - Apply rsplit in DataFrame column using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, substring, strsplit

I've a dataframe with the following structure (3 columns):

```
DATE,QUOTE,SOURCE
2019-11-21,1ºTEST/2ºTEST DONE, KAGGLE
```

What I am trying to do is make a substring on QUOTE column in order to generate anew column only with the words after the last occurrence (in this case the word 'TEST').

My expected result:

```
DATE,QUOTE, SATUS, SOURCE
2019-11-21,1ºTEST/2ºTEST DONE, DONE, KAGGLE
```

For that I'm trying with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (filename)
split = lambda x: len(x['QUOTE'].rsplit('TEST',1)[0])
df["STATUS"] = df.apply(split, axis=1)
print(df["STATUS"].unique())
```

However I'm just printing numbers not 'DONE'.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of split you are using [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), that returns the length of sequence (an integer),

```
len([1, 'Done'])  # returns 2
```

You need to access the last index, for example:

```
df['STATUS'] = df.QUOTE.str.rsplit('TEST').str[-1]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         DATE               QUOTE  SOURCE STATUS
0  2019-11-21  1ºTEST/2ºTEST DONE  KAGGLE   DONE
```

Or if you want to use apply, just change the definition of split:

```
split = lambda x: x['QUOTE'].rsplit('TEST', 1)[-1]
df["STATUS"] = df.apply(split, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         DATE               QUOTE  SOURCE STATUS
0  2019-11-21  1ºTEST/2ºTEST DONE  KAGGLE   DONE
```

Note than using lambda to create named functions is consider a not so good practice.